# Таймер для FireFox

Tags: веб-программирование

Нужно что-то вроде таймера для FireFox, который будет показывать время прошедшее с момента обновления страницы. Можно такое сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно.
Надо просто написать UserJS

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include *
// ==/UserScript==
start=(new Date()).getTime();
window.setInterval(function(){
    document.title=Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime()-start)/1000);
}, 340);
```

Устанавливаете расширение [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), код приведенный выше сохраняете в файл `*.user.js`, открываете его через FireFox и со всем соглашаетесь.